# Getting underlying IP used in database connection

Tags: c#, networking

I'm trying to see how pooled database connections are affecting the load balancing of commands between a fleet of read only MySQL database replicas.  The data source in the connection string is a DNS entry that has several entries which are served to the client in a round robin fashion.

Is it possible to take the database connection object and extract the IP address that the connection is using to connect?

**Update**

In this code example:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection _mySQL = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(_AuroraClusterEndPoint);
```

**Update #2**

My question is more of how to determine what IP an active connection is using and not really how to evenly distribute traffic.

Pseudo Code:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection _mySQL = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(_AuroraClusterEndPoint);

_mySQL.Open();
Console.WriteLine(_mySQL.ConnectionInfo.IPAddress); //This is the unknown part
_mySQL.Close();
```

How would I take `_mySQL` and extract the IP address it is using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no,

Don't store the dns hostname in your connection string.  Build the connection string on the fly, (anyway you can or want to store the information).

When building the connection string in code lookup the dns alias/host name to get it's ip addresses (should only return 1 ipv4 address)

```
IPAddress[] ipv4Addresses = Array.FindAll(
    Dns.GetHostEntry("hostnamehere").AddressList,
    a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

Test it and debug if you get multiple addresses.

Once you get the IP you now know what IP address the round robin gave the request, you can log it, then build your connection string with the IP address instead of the host name.

Here's a rough and dirty example I wrote in 5 minutes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ipAddress;
            var newConnectionString = SwapConnectionStringDNSWithIP("Server=google.com;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;", out ipAddress);
            Console.WriteLine(ipAddress);
            Console.WriteLine(newConnectionString);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public static string SwapConnectionStringDNSWithIP(string connectionString, out string ipAddress)
        {
            ipAddress = null;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
                return null;
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var pParts = connectionString.Split(';');
            foreach (var part in pParts)
            {
                if (part.IndexOf('=') == -1)
                    break;
                var sParts = part.Split('=');
                if (sParts.Length != 2)
                    break;
                string key = sParts[0].ToLower().Trim();
                string value = sParts[1];
                if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    dict.Add(key, value);
                }
            }
            var server = dict.ContainsKey("server") ? dict["server"] : null;
            if (server == null)
                return null;

            var ret = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);
            var addresses = ret.AddressList.Select(a => a.GetAddressBytes()).ToArray();
            if (addresses != null && addresses.Length > 0)
            {
                ipAddress = string.Join(".", addresses[0]);
                dict["server"] = ipAddress;
                var newConnectionString = string.Join(string.Empty, dict.Keys.Select(k => k + "=" + dict[k] + ";").ToArray());
                return newConnectionString;
            }                      
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question with an example of what I'm looking for.  I don't think I was very clear on what I was after.

Comment: you need to break down the connection string, get the host name out of it, do a DNS lookup on it, put the ipaddress in the connection string instead of the host name, then proceed to create the connection using the looked up IP Address.  As mentioned above.  That ip address will be what the round robin DNS gave you.

Comment: So yeah it's possible, but you need to extract the dns host name from the connection string, use Dns.GetHostEntry to get the ip, then put the ip in the connection string instead.  If it were SqlServer you could use SqlConnectionStringBuilder, mysql you might have to parse it out with string manipulation.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include full working code for replacing the server in the connection string with the lookup IP Address.  This should be the IP Address from DNS (round robin) and should change on different dns resolutions if round robin gives it a different one.

But with this you know what IP in code it's using for the connection string.  So you can add that info to logs etc etc, or even queries.